# How to iterate through dataframe based on timer?

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, api-design

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id   text     number  url
1    test1    123     a.com
2    test2    456     b.com
```

Once per day I want to iterate through only one row of a dataframe into an api. Example on 7/28, send number `123` text `test1`. On 7/29 send `456` text `test2`.

Here is the code that looks through the entire dataframe, but not sure how to only one row per day?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data = {
    'phone': row.number,
    'message':row.text,
    'url':row.URL,
    }

    r = requests.post(URL,headers=headers,params=data)

    print(r.text)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with pandas? You just need to store the row number somewhere.

Comment: @roganjosh I didnt know that. Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: Do you intend to leave the program running indefinitely? A better idea would be to use a scheduler such as crontab.

Comment: I don't know what example to give. Pandas is for data processing as fast as possible (in python) and you're asking how to do something once per day

Comment: @Spinor8 eventually running it indefinitely but for now crontab is fine. I need to prove out the concept that yes on daily basis I can send a message incrimentally.

Comment: @roganjosh I understand it is for data processing, but i love the simplicity of how the strucutre is setup .

Comment: There is _nothing_ simple about pandas. It also has no part to play in what you're trying to do. Use the `csv` module or something.

Comment: @roganjosh if you can not help why comment?

Comment: You want me to make an answer that iterates through a dataframe and makes a single request per day? When I get home I can do that. It would also be a terrible approach.

Comment: @roganjosh got the answer below thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data = {
    'phone': row.number,
    'message':row.text,
    'url':row.URL,
    }

    r = requests.post(URL,headers=headers,params=data)
    print(r.text)
    time.sleep(86400)
```